# How is the group $O(p,q)$ defined wrt quadratic forms?

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, quadratic-forms

Given a symmetric matrix $Q$ defining a quadratic form with signature $(p,q)$, the group of matrices $X$ which preserve $Q$, i.e.
$$
Q(Xu, Xv) = Q(u,v),
$$
is denoted $O(p,q)$.

So, I understand that, for instance, for a non-degenerate indefinite binary quadratic form $Q$, the group of matrices preserving the form is $O(1,1)$, and this is a group of dimension $1$.

However, I am confused because surely the group of matrices preserving a quadratic form depends on the quadratic form? For instance the matrices preserving 
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad \text{and} \quad \quad B = \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 1 \\
  1 & -2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
are going to be different - in this case
$\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  2 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$
preserves $A$ but not $B$.

With this in mind, how is $O(p,q)$ defined? I can find no explanation suggesting $O(p,q)$ depends on the choice of $Q$, but if it is the same group regardless of the choice of $Q$, then what differentiates, say, $O(1,1)$ from $GL_2(\mathbb{N})$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix representing a bilinear form, then the group of transformations preserving this form is $\mathscr{O}(A) = \{ X \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}): X^t A X = A\}$.

Now let $A, B \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be two matrices representing a quadratic form with signature $(p,q)$ (where $p+q = n$). Then Sylvester's law of inertia tells you that $A = P^tBP$ for some $P \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

I leave it an exercise for you to show that $\mathscr{O}(A) = P^{-1} \mathscr{O}(B) P$.

That is, the groups $O(p,q)$ you get with different forms are usually not the same, but they will be conjugate in $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Is the $P$ unique?

Comment: @Filippo: No, taking $P' = XP$ for any matrix $X$ that normalizes $\mathscr{O}(B)$ works as well. For example $P' = cP$ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

$O(p,q)$ depends of the choice of the signature of the quadratic form $Q(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{i=p}x_i^2-\sum_{i=p+1}^{i=n}x_i^2$ with $p+q=n$. Here the signature is $(p,q)$. You can always find a basis where the quadratic form has that expression. Two quadratic forms with the same signature yields to the same automorphisms group.

Comment: Yes - that's why I'm confused. For instance the example in my question. $A$ and $B$ are both indefinite binary quadratic forms, and are therefore (presumably) both preserved by $O(1,1)$. But the *actual matrices* preserving $A$ and $B$ are different. Hence my confusion.

(Ed: hang on, just reading your edit)

Comment: So are you saying that all indefinite quadratic forms are equivalent to each other? Instinctively that seems like it just *can't* be true ...

Comment: As I said in my answer, for every quadratic form, there is an orthonormal basis $(e_1,...,e_n)$ with $Q(e_i)=1, $ or $-1$.  If you consider the bilinear form $B$ associated to $Q$, $B(e_i,e_j)=0 $ for $i\neq j$. So for the matrix $A$ and $B$ you have to find an orthonormal basis (with GrammSchmidt for example )to find the signature and determine if they are isomorphic.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I still don't understand. So the matrix above which preserves $A$, is that in $O(1,1)$? It preserves one quadratic form, but it doesn't preserve another one, so is it therefore *not* in $O(1,1)$? Or is it in $O(1,1)$ but only under some conjugation? Or what?

Comment: For $A$, write $x=ue_1+ve_2, Q(x,x)=  u^2Q(e_1,e_1)+2uvQ(e_1,e_2)+v^2Q(e_2,e_2)=u^2+2uv-v^2=(u+v)^2-2v^2$. Consider the basis $e_1-e_2, e_2$, you have $Q(e_1+e_2,e_2)=0, Q(e_1+e_2,e_1+e_2)=2,Q(e_2,e_2)=-1$. Write $x=a({{e_1+e_2}\over 2})+be_2, Q(x)=Q(a({{e_1+e_2}\over 2})+be_2,a({{e_1+e_2}\over 2})+be_2)=a^2-b^2$ so the signature is $(1,1)$.

Comment: I *know* that the signature of $A$ is $(1,1)$. I know that the signature of $B$ is $(1,1)$. That is not my problem. My problem is that $A$ and $B$ are clearly preserved by entirely different matrices, so I don't understand why the "group of matrices preserving the quadratic form" is the same group for both of them.

Comment: You can do the same with $B$ $Q(x,x)=u^2+2uv-2v^2$, consider the basis $2e_1+e_2,e_2$, you have $Q(2e_1+e_2,e_2)=0, Q(2e_1+e_2,2e_1+e_2)=6, Q(e_2,e_2)=-2$ $x=c{{2e_1+e_2}\over 2}+de_2$ You have $Q(x,x)=c^2-d^2$. You see that the signature is again $(1,1)$ so the form are equivalent.

Comment: The orthogonal group does not depend on the base chosen to write the quadratic form, the signature is $(1,1)$ means that there exists a basis where the quadratic form has the expression $u^2-v^2$ thus two quadratic forms with same signature yields to the same orthogonal group.

Comment: OK, so does that mean that my matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 2 \\
  2 & 5 \\
\end{pmatrix}$ *is* in $O(1,1)$? But maybe under some change of basis, which depends on $A$?

Comment: Yes, it means that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we write $D_{pq}$ as the $n$ by $n$ diagonal matrix, with $n = p+q,$ with the first $p$ diagonal elements equal to $+1,$ then $q$ diagonal elements $-1.$

Theorem. Over the REAL NUMBERS, any symmetric matrix $A$ with $p$ positive eigenvalues and $q$ negative eigenvalues can be written as
$$ A = P^T D_{pq} P $$
where $\det P \neq 0.$ Taking $Q = P^{-1},$ we could also write
$$ Q^T A Q =  D_{pq} . $$

This relationship is called **congruence**. It is the correct way to modify quadratic forms. The theorem is Sylvester's Law of Inertia.

IF  $$ R^T AR = A, $$ then
$$  (P R Q)^T D_{pq} (P R Q) =  D_{pq} . $$

IF  $$ S^T  D_{pq} S =  D_{pq}, $$ then
$$  (QSP)^T A (QSP) =  A . $$