# Prove that surrounded by zero exist smooth function $y(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let the function $G$ be such that $G(x)=\sum_{ij}G_{ij}(x)x_ix_j$ for some $G_{ij}\in C^{\infty}$ that vanish at zero.   Prove that in a neighborhood of zero there  exists a  smooth function $y(x)$ such that:
> $$Q(x+y(x))=Q(x)+G(x), y(0)=0, dy(0)=0$$ where $Q(x)$ is a nondegenerate quadratic form.

I have an idea to use $F(x,y)=Q(x+y)-Q(x)-G(x)$ and then use the theorem:

*Let $r$ - set of all smooth functions vanishing at zero. 
Assume that for smooth function $F$ we can write $F(x,0)$ as $F(x,0)=\sum_{ij}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y_i}(x,0) \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_j}(x,0)\phi_{ij}(x)$ for some $\phi_{ij}\in r$. 
Then $F(x,y(x))=0$ has in the surroundings $x=0$ smooth solution $y(x)$ such that $y_i(x)=\sum_{j} \frac{\partial F}{\partial y_j}(x,0)z_{ij}(x)$ for some $z_{ij}\in r$.*

My idea stems from the fact that $F(x,0)=Q(x)-Q(x)-G(x)=-G(x)$ but I don't really know what to do with it.

Can I ask for help?

Comment: What is "zeroing in zero"; what is "zeroing at zero"?

Comment: @kimchilover I'm sorry but I didn't know how to translate it. So zeroing at zero is when $F(\vec{x})=0$ for $\vec{x}=0$

Comment: Maybe "vanishing" a better translation than "zeroing".  What's the original.?

Comment: @kimchilover yes! That's what I meant, thank you! Let me use your translation and edit the post so that the content does not confuse others users

Comment: Are you trying to prove the [Morse Lemma](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Morse_lemma)?

Comment: @kimchilover no, I never heard about it

Comment: I have edited your question; I hope I did it right.  I think the Morse Lemma (see [this as well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma)) implies your result.  But I doubt if a proof from first principles of the ML is easier than the proof you are contemplating.

Comment: @kimchilover but in the Morse lemma it is assumed that $y(0)=0, dy(0)=0$ and in my task I have to prove it. So I think these are the opposite implications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way of deriving the OP's desired result, using a *deus ex machina* argument that I happened to know.

Given $G$ and a non-degenerate quadratic form $Q$ as stated, the
function $f(x)=Q(x)+G(x)$ has a non-degenerate critical point at $x=0$, with $f(0)=0$, $df(0)=0$, and $d^2f(0)=2Q$.  By the [Morse Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_theory#Morse_lemma) there exists a diffeomorphism $u$ in a neighborhood of $0$ such that $f(x)= Q(u(x))$, with $u(0)=0$.  Let $\epsilon(x)=u(x)-(u(0)+du(0)x)=u(x)-du(0)x$ be the remainder of the linear Taylor approximation to $u$ at $0$.  We have $\epsilon(x)=o(\|x\|)$.

By matching Taylor expansions of $f(x)$ and $Q(u(x))=Q(0+du(0)x+o(\|x\|))$ through quadratic terms, we see that $Q(du(0)v)=Q(v)$ for all $v$.
That is, the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ in the Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ is the same as that of $Q(x)$, which is $2q_{ij}$.  The corresponding coefficient for $Q(u(x))$ is $2\sum_{kl} q_{kl}(\partial_i u_k)(\partial_j u_l)$.  Since $f(x)=Q(u(x))$ for all $x$ close to $0$, the coefficients of $x_ix_j$ must match.

Thus, $f(x) = Q(u(x))=Q(du(0)^{-1}u(x))=Q(x+y(x))$, where $y(x)=du(0)^{-1}\epsilon(x)$.
This is the desired formula.  The matching Taylor expansion verifies that $du(0)\in \mathcal O(Q)$, in the notation of this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1884426/how-is-the-group-op-q-defined-wrt-quadratic-forms); this step is needed because of the notational mismatch between the way the current problem is stated and the more coordinate-free way the Morse Lemma is usually stated.

Comment: Why $d^2f(0)=2Q$?

Comment: The second derivative of $qx^2$ at $x=0$ is $2q$. The Hessian matrix of the quadratic form $Q(x)$ at $x=0$ is $2Q$.  If you and I defined $f=Q/2 + G$ we would have $d^2f(0)=Q$.

Comment: Why you have $Q(du(0)v)=Q(v)$, not $Q(du(0)v)=Q(u(v))$?

Comment: I have edited my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and of course, I mark your answer as the best! However, I would like to ask you if you have an idea of how to prove the second part of the task, which I did not mention in the post: "Prove $x \mapsto x+y$ is diffeomorphism of some $0$ neighborhood", where $y$ is a smooth function from my post.

Comment: Isn't this the inverse function theorem: a smooth perturbation of the identity function has an inverse.

Comment: So the proof will look like this: from the character of $y$ from your solution, $x \mapsto x+y(x)$ we can write as $x \mapsto x+du(0)^{-1}r(x)$. That's why it is a function $\in C^1$. Moreover $df(0)$ is reversible so from the inverse function theorem $x \mapsto  x+y(x)$ is  diffeomorphism of some $0$ neighborhood. Is it clear? Is it sufficient proof?

Comment: Sufficient for me, but maybe not for your audience.   I'd look at the exact statement of the theorem in your favorite textbook, and go from there.