# Linear maps preserving a revolution cone

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-cone

Let $C$ be the cone of $R^{n+1}$ defined by
$$ C=\lbrace x=(x_1,..,x_{n+1})|\quad \sum_1^n x_i^2 >x_{n+1}^2 \rbrace.$$

I am interested in the set $\mathcal{C}$ of $n\times n$ matrices $M$ which preserve the cone
$$ M.C \subset C $$

I am trying to figure out what are the properties of this set, and I search lecture notes / references describing it. Can anyone help?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you attempted the case $n=1$ ?

Answer (score 2):

The matrices preserving the (relativity) quadratic form :

$$q(x)=x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2-x_{n+1}^2$$

and in particular preserving its sign are the matrices verifying:

$$MQM^T=Q$$

where $$Q=diag(\underbrace{1,1...1}_{n \ \text{terms}},-1)$$

These matrices constitute a classical group named $O(n,1)$.

For more see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884426).

Remark: In the case $n=1$, the group $0(1,1)$ is constituted of matrices of the form:

$$R_a=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(a)&\sinh(a)\\ \sinh(a)&\cosh(a)\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. These matrices map the cone to the cone. Can we say something about matrices that map the cone to a subset of the cone?